# SAPUI5: "Unexpected token function" for async / wait

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-web-ide

I am trying to execute the following function with async/await in WebIDE SCP, but there'are un error

> "ESLINT : Parsing error : Unexpected token function

[image]

I think that I have to use Node.js, but how to use it in webIDE ?

Kindly help me?

Answer (score 0):

> I think that I have to use Node.js, but how to use it in webIDE ?

No, you don't. You need to [tell ESLint that you're using ES2015+ ("ES6") features](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options):

> `ecmaVersion` - set to 3, 5 (default), 6, 7, 8, 9, or 10 to specify the version of ECMAScript syntax you want to use. You can also set to 2015 (same as 6), 2016 (same as 7), 2017 (same as 8), 2018 (same as 9), or 2019 (same as 10) to use the year-based naming.

Comment: Hi Crowder, thanks for your reply. I have seen your document of ESLint . I have tried to create a new file .eslintrc.json with {"parserOptions":  {"ecmaVersion": 6,..}}, then added  /* eslint .eslintrc.json */ in file controller.js ... But, there's no change..

Comment: @dieuhuynh - You probably need to refer to the documentation for the SAP Web IDE to find out how to set the ESLint configuration it uses.

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2017
}
```

to the end of your `.eslintrc` file. This should fix the error. I just had the same issue and it works for me in the current WebIDE version.